# StartActivityForResult() and OnActivityResult() functionality between fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having two fragments in my android application, when i move from one fragment to another fragment and did some work and while coming back i want to pass some result to my first fragment. Is this possible if yes means how Please help

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. check this doc. Fragment is hosted by a activity. communicate value back to activity. then you can communicate back to another activity that hosts the first fragment

Answer (score 0):

Use callbacks to interact between Fragments [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to let the activity apply changes to its fragment than passing values directly between fragments. Let your Activity implement a FragmentListener interface with onQuery(Bundle data) and onResult(Bundle data) methods.

Create a FragmentListener varaible in each of your fragments and then override onAttach() of each fragment as:

```
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    //---register parent activity for events---
    try{
        fragmentListener = (FragmentListener) activity;
    }catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException("Parent activity must implement interface FragmentListener.");
    }
  }
```

This will enforce your child fragments to be automatically registered to parent Activity.

Now you can call your Activity from fragments.

On the other side, your Activity can always search for a fragment using getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentA") or findFragmentById("FragmentA"). If it can find your Fragment, Then it can cast it into your FragmentA class and call its methods. Same can be done with FragmentB or any other fragment..